# IllegalArgumentException within JAVA SPRING REST Controller

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm receiving following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:471) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:667) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_51]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_51]
```

My REST controller:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/users/{name}")
public @ResponseBody SystemUser getUserByName(@PathVariable("name") String name) {

    List<SystemUser> users = dataProvider.findSystemUsersByName(name);
    if (users != null && users.size() > 0) {            
        return users.get(0);
    }
    else {          
        return null;
    }
}

@GetMapping(path = "/usersByEmail/{email}")
public @ResponseBody SystemUser getUserByEmail(@PathVariable("email") String email) {

    List<SystemUser> users = dataProvider.findSystemUsersByEmail(email);
    if (users != null && users.size() > 0) {            
        return users.get(0);
    }
    else {          
        return null;
    }
}
```

I'm passing simple strings without any special characters (also no '@') as parameters.

Could anyone tell why I'm getting the above exception and how to fix it. Thank you very much!

Comment: What is the string you pass which fails the request? Try URL encode the parameters.

Comment: in my case it was just 'zu'. Could you please explain what exactly you mean with 'URL encode the parameters'? Thank you.

Comment: Also This mapping won't work, as there is no way to make a different between `/users/username` and `/users/username@somedomain.com`. For Spring both are basically the same. (Unless this code isn't the code you are actually using!).

Comment: Yes, you are right M. Deinum. The code I posted before was not the actual code I used. Please have a look at the corrected version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem!

It was actually in the client implementation.

I mistakenly wrote following code in my angularjs client:

```
// Retrieves user by name
function GetByUsername(username) {
    return $http.get('http://localhost:5555/demo/users/{name}' + username).then(
        handleSuccess, handleError('Error getting user by username'));
}

// Retrieves user by email
function GetByEmail(email) {
    return $http.get('http://localhost:5555/demo/usersByEmail/{email}' + email).then(
        handleSuccess, handleError('Error getting user by email'));
}
```

instead of

```
// Retrieves user by name
function GetByUsername(username) {
    return $http.get('http://localhost:5555/demo/users/' + username).then(
        handleSuccess, handleError('Error getting user by username'));
}

// Retrieves user by email
function GetByEmail(email) {
    return $http.get('http://localhost:5555/demo/usersByEmail/' + email).then(
        handleSuccess, handleError('Error getting user by email'));
}
```

Comment: Correct. The request url with '{' and '}' are not allowed in some server versions. Thats why you were getting errror. With below server version '{' and '}' are allowed, Fixed in:

- 8.5.x for 8.5.12 onwards
- 8.0.x for 8.0.42 onwards
- 7.0.x for 7.0.76 onwards